# Can all of this be done in one function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, function, excel-2010

I have not found a way to do this.
I have a large SQL statement that does the following:

1. checks for two temp tables, if found deletes them
2. Declares local variables
3. Sets local variables
4. runs SQL statement1 which inserts into #tmp1 (temp table)
5. runs SQL statement2 which inserts into #tmp2 (temp table)
6. runs SQL statement3 which selects from #tmp1 and #temp2 (temp table) and returns pivot results

Running this in a query window works fine but I'd like to make one function (or something) to do the same.

EDIT1: I seem to be able to call a table function from excel and return those results but I can't call a stored proc from excel, I get an error.  The problem with the table function is that I can't delete (drop) tables.

Comment: What problem do you have when you put all of this in a stored procedure?  It should work just fine.  Maybe the problem is terminology.  You want a "stored procedure", not a "function".

Comment: I didn't think I could return a table, thought I had to use a table function.  Would I be able to call this from Excel?

Comment: Steps 4 through 6 can likely be condensed to a single SELECT that avoids the use of temp tables, but there's not enough info here for us to tell you what that query might look like

Comment: Can't you call an `EXEC sproc` from Excel? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693967/table-in-excel-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameter-field-in-workbook

Comment: Rubens - it seems following those instructions I can call a stored proc from Excel.  I was using a slightly different method that wasn't working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.OneFunction AS

--Checks for two temp tables, if found delete them
IF OBJECT_ID('#Frob') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP #Frob
IF OBJECT_ID('#Grob') IS NOT NULL
    DROP #Grob

--Declare local variables
DECLARE @some int;
DECLARE @localVariables nvarchar(max);

--Sets local variables
SET @some = 69;
SET @localVariables = N'Tĥḗ qᴜįċᴋ ᶀʀᴏᴡɴ ƒᴏx ᴊᴜᴍᴘěɖ ᴏᴠḝʀ'  

--runs SQL statement1 which inserts into #tmp1 (temp table)
INSERT INTO #tep1
SELECT 'Hi'

--runs SQL statement2 which inserts into #tmp2 (temp table)
INSERT INTO #tmp2
SELECT 'Low'

--runs SQL statement3 which selects from #tmp1 and #temp2 (temp table) and returns pivot results
SELECT *
FROM #tmp1
   FULL OUTER JOIN #tmp2 ON 1=1
PIVOT BY SOMEONE WHO KNOWS THE INSANE PIVOT SYNTAX
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: Ian - I just edited my OP to include calling this from excel.