# Excel table bound to SQL server with user-specified filter criteria/parameters without using MSQuery or VBA - possible?

Tags: excel, vba

This post shows how one can use MS Query to load an Excel table from SQL Server, with user-specified filter criteria (parameters) read from cells in the spreadsheet:

[Table in Excel from SQL Server stored procedure with parameter field in workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693967/table-in-excel-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameter-field-in-workbook)

I really liked the end result of that approach (part of the reason being that it was totally VBA free), but unfortunately, it seems that method has a 256 character limit on criteria.

I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to do something similar, but not using MS Query, and preferably not using VBA?

Comment: Can you set up a `View` in MS SQL that can a) provide a shortened field list that can be called with * and b) provide some of the `WHERE` criteria that is common to different MS Query calls?

Comment: I'm already calling a stored proc, the problem is the parameter content itself is > 256 characters (and no way around it).